# How to update dynamic multiple input (user can add those input themself)?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, state

I have a form. Initially there is some default values (user name and address). When user click `add`, there is an extra input which user can enter another name and address, and the extra name and address will store in `additionConfigs`.

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-pateu-2uy4rt

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  const [additionConfigs, setAdditionConfigs] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setValue([
        {
          id: 1,
          baseName: "XXX",
          config: {
            name: "Kenny",
            address: "New york"
          }
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          baseName: "YYY",
          config: {
            name: "Ben",
            address: "Boston"
          }
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          baseName: "ZZZ",
          config: {
            name: "Mary",
            address: "Los Angeles"
          }
        }
      ]);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  const onAddBaseConfig = (item) => {
    setAdditionConfigs((preValue) => [
      ...preValue,
      {
        id: item.id,
        config: {
          name: "",
          address: ""
        }
      }
    ]);
  };
  console.log(additionConfigs);
  const onChangeName = (e, id) => {
    setAdditionConfigs((preValue) => {
      const newValue = preValue.map((v) => {
        if (v.id === id) {
          return {
            ...v,
            config: {
              ...v.config,
              name: e.target.value
            }
          };
        }
        return v;
      });
      return newValue;
    });
  };
  const onChangeAddress = (e, id) => {
    setAdditionConfigs((preValue) => {
      const newValue = preValue.map((v) => {
        if (v.id === id) {
          return {
            ...v,
            config: {
              ...v.config,
              address: e.target.value
            }
          };
        }
        return v;
      });
      return newValue;
    });
  };
  return (
    <>
      {value.length > 0 &&
        value.map((v, index) => (
          <div className="item" key={index}>
            <div className="item">
              {v.config.name} &nbsp;
              {v.config.address} &nbsp;
              {additionConfigs.length > 0 &&
                additionConfigs
                  .filter((config) => config.id === v.id)
                  .map((config) => (
                    <div>
                      <label>name</label>
                      <input
                        value={config.config.name}
                        onChange={(e) => onChangeName(e, config.id)}
                      />
                      <label>address</label>
                      <input
                        value={config.config.address}
                        onChange={(e) => onChangeAddress(e, config.id)}
                      />
                    </div>
                  ))}
            </div>
            <button onClick={() => onAddBaseConfig(v)}>Add</button>
          </div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Currently, I use `config.id` to update the extra name and address, but there is an issue that if user add two or more extra name and address input, when updating the first one, the second will update, too.

How do I update respectively? Giving each group of input a flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the component should not modify the base `value` as it is set by a `useEffect`, but keep a `additionConfigs` which need to support any amount of config inputs, perhaps one solution could be to make `additionConfigs` state an object.

The `additionConfigs` object could have `id` from base `value` as key and an array of configs as value, and perhaps each config need its own `id`, so that they can be controlled by the added `input`, without major refactor of the existing code structure.

Forked live with modifications: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/additionconfigs-03cjf4?file=/src/App.js)

Perhaps try the following as an example:

Define `additionConfigs` state as an object:

```
const [additionConfigs, setAdditionConfigs] = useState({});
```

Update logic for `additionConfigs` when adding a config `input`:

(*The `id` logic here is only adding previous `id++`, and should probably be replaced by a unique id generator in actual project*)

```
  const onAddBaseConfig = (item) => {
    setAdditionConfigs((preValue) => {
      const preConfigs = preValue?.[item.id];
      const newId = preConfigs
        ? preConfigs.reduce((acc, cur) => (cur.id > acc ? cur.id : acc), 0) + 1
        : 1;
      return {
        ...preValue,
        [item.id]: preConfigs
          ? [
              ...preConfigs,
              {
                id: newId,
                config: {
                  name: "",
                  address: ""
                }
              }
            ]
          : [
              {
                id: newId,
                config: {
                  name: "",
                  address: ""
                }
              }
            ]
      };
    });
  };
```

Update logic for a config `input` for `name`, a `baseId` is added as an argument as each base `value` can have multiple configs:

```
  const onChangeName = (e, id, baseId) => {
    setAdditionConfigs((preValue) => {
      const newArr = preValue[baseId].map((v) => {
        if (v.id === id) {
          return {
            ...v,
            config: {
              ...v.config,
              name: e.target.value
            }
          };
        }
        return v;
      });
      return { ...preValue, [baseId]: newArr };
    });
  };
```

Same but for `address`:

```
  const onChangeAddress = (e, id, baseId) => {
    setAdditionConfigs((preValue) => {
      const newArr = preValue[baseId].map((v) => {
        if (v.id === id) {
          return {
            ...v,
            config: {
              ...v.config,
              address: e.target.value
            }
          };
        }
        return v;
      });
      return { ...preValue, [baseId]: newArr };
    });
  };
```

Output with the changes:

```
<>
  {value.length > 0 &&
    value.map((v, index) => (
      <div className="item" key={index}>
        <div className="item">
          {v.config.name} &nbsp;
          {v.config.address} &nbsp;
          {additionConfigs?.[v.id] &&
            additionConfigs?.[v.id].length > 0 &&
            additionConfigs?.[v.id].map((config, index) => (
              <div key={config.id}>
                <label>name</label>
                <input
                  value={config.config.name}
                  onChange={(e) => onChangeName(e, config.id, v.id)}
                />
                <label>address</label>
                <input
                  value={config.config.address}
                  onChange={(e) => onChangeAddress(e, config.id, v.id)}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => onAddBaseConfig(v)}>Add</button>
      </div>
    ))}
</>
```